# \columnbreak doesn't work

Tags: page-breaking, multicol

With the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\noindent Vediamo un po' di testo a due colonne. Proviamo a cambiar colonna: \columnbreak
\texttt{\textbackslash columnbreak} serve a passare alla colonna successiva, ossia ad inserire un \emph{Column Break}, un'interruzione di colonna, come direbbe Word.
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

I should get a two-column bit of text with one column containing the text up till `colonna:` and the other one contanining the rest. Trouble is, I'm pretty far from that:

[image]

Adding `\\` before `\columnbreak` or substituting `\columnbreak` with a negative `\penalty` simply doesn't work either. So what do I do to get from `\texttt{\textbackslash columnbreak}` on onto column 2? And why is `\columnbreak` being thus totally ignored?

Comment: you need to add blank line or and explicit paragraph break (`\par`) before `\columnbreak` for it to work

Comment: @dcmst yep, that works. But why do I need that blank line or explicit paragraph break?

Comment: I was just going to suggest to wait for the appropriate, in-depth, explanation :D

Comment: @dcmst egreg's is longer than mine but it did take him a hole minute longer to write:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Speaking of slowness, it took me more than both of you to type just a single line comment :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This example shows that `\columnbreak` *is* obeyed:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\noindent Vediamo un po' di testo a due colonne. Proviamo a cambiar colonna: \columnbreak
\texttt{\textbackslash columnbreak} serve a passare alla colonna successiva, ossia a
inserire un \emph{Column Break}, un'interruzione di colonna, come in altri programmi
di scrittura. Chissà che succede ora qui avendo aggiunto testo.
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Let's try without the `italian` option and `fontenc`, so that the output should be similar to yours

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\noindent Vediamo un po' di testo a due colonne. Proviamo a cambiar colonna: \columnbreak
\texttt{\textbackslash columnbreak} serve a passare alla colonna successiva, ossia a
inserire un \emph{Column Break}, un'interruzione di colonna, come in altri programmi
di scrittura. Chissà che succede ora qui avendo aggiunto testo.
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

When `\columnbreak` appears inside a paragraph, the corresponding penalty is inserted after the line where `\columnbreak` happens to fall. In both cases it falls in the line containing `\texttt{\textbackslash columnbreak}`. Changing the input to be

```
\noindent Vediamo un po' di testo a due colonne. Proviamo a cambiar colonna:\columnbreak
\ \texttt{\textbackslash columnbreak} serve a passare alla colonna successiva, ossia a
inserire un \emph{Column Break}, un'interruzione di colonna, come in altri programmi
di scrittura. Chissà che succede ora qui avendo aggiunto testo.
```

the penalty is attached to the colon, instead of the backslash and indeed the output is

[image]

If you want to add a column break exactly after the colon, though, you should do

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\noindent Vediamo un po' di testo a due colonne. Proviamo a 
cambiar colonna:\columnbreak\linebreak
\verb|\columnbreak| serve a passare alla colonna successiva, ossia a
inserire un \emph{Column Break}, un'interruzione di colonna, come in altri programmi
di scrittura. Chissà che succede ora qui avendo aggiunto testo.
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any difference between `\\` and `\linebreak`?

Comment: @MickG Of course there is! ``\ `` just inserts a normal space, `\linebreak` forces a new line.

Comment: Sorry, damn markup :). I meant `\\ `, not `\ `. I know `\ ` is a space, but `\\ ` is a linebreak, isn't it @egreg?

Comment: @MickG With ``\\`` you abruptly end a line, with `\linebreak` it's filled up.

Comment: "filled up" in what sense?

Comment: @MickG Why don't you try with some examples for yourself?

Answer (score 7):

`\columnbreak` like `\vspace` and `\pagebreak` etc if used in horizontal mode inserts itself into a `\vadjust` node that TeX's paragraph breaker will insert *after the current line of text is broken into lines*. Only once the `\vadjust` node contents are interpreted in vertical mode will the underlying penalty affect the column breaking.

In this case the node (just) gets put into the line with your `\columnbreak` text so has an effect *after* that line, it is easier to see with more text that id does force a break:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\noindent Vediamo un po' di testo a due colonne. Proviamo a cambiar colonna: \columnbreak
\texttt{\textbackslash columnbreak} serve a passare alla colonna successiva, ossia ad inserire un \emph{Column Break}, un'interruzione di colonna, come direbbe Word.

zzz

zzz

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```